# Apply a dynamic variable to a condition Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

i am new at Dax and I searched in google but seems not working, although looks easy i haven found the proper result, I have a dashboard as showed in picture, I was trying to find the operator with the max wellid and then use it in an if condition.

As you can see in the [attached report pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE2XI.png) the Max WELLID belongs to an operator BBL OPERATING, I created this measure to identify the max wellid and to find the operator:

```
_CURRENT = 
VAR TOPWELL = MAX('Well List'[WellID])
RETURN
CALCULATE(MAX('Well List'[Operator]), KEEPFILTERS( FILTER( ALL('Well 
List'[WellName], 'Well List'[Operator], 'Well List'[WellID]), 'Well 
List'[WellID] = TOPWELL)))
```

This returns the Operator mentioned above, but as you can see, there are more rows with this operator name in the table, so based on the above measure, how can i use the measure to add 1 or 0 if operator name = BBL OPERATOR? i tried:

```
if( [_CURRENT] IN VALUES('Well List'[Operator]), 1, 0)
```

but this puts 1 or 0 to the whole column, any idea?

Comment: Please provide more context of the problem. If you are new to DAX maybe you are approaching the problem in the "wrong way for DAX".

Comment: @Seymour I am sure I am approaching it wrong, here is my question in Power bi community: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Re-published-Dax-measure-to-filter-the-data-in-the-chart-only-by/m-p/1180958#M531302